# Ruby: How do I use the literal value of a variable in an eval?

Tags: ruby

I want to use the value of a variable in my eval. How can I do that?

The following code snippet:

```
class Adder
  def initialize(i)
    @i = i
  end

  def method_missing(methodName)
    self.class.class_eval do
        def #{methodName}
          return @i+20
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Gives the error *formal argument cannot be an instance variable* on Line 9

Comment: I want to define a function with the name helloworld.

Comment: You eval is also wrong.. it will throw argument error,,

Comment: You should use `define_method` method to define methods in runtime.

Comment: @ShaileshTainwala, if you receive answer to your question, please mark correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eval can take a string, so just construct whatever string you want an pass it to eval.

```
myString = "helloworld"
eval <<END
  def #{myString}
     puts "Hello World!"
  end
END
```

Comment: I'm getting an error despite using your suggestion. Can you take a look at the updated question please?

Comment: No, you didn't use my suggestion.  Look carefully and you will see that you are still trying to pass a block to eval, whereas I passed a heredoc string.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method)  method to define methods in runtime:

```
my_string = 'helloworld'
define_method my_string do
  # body of your method
end
```

If you want to pass arguments to the newly defined method you can do this through the block parameters:

```
define_method 'method_name' do |arg1, arg2|
  # body of your method
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For your example,

```
class Adder
  def initialize(i)
    @i = i
  end

  def method_missing(methodName)
    self.class.send :define_method, methodName do
        return @i+20
    end
      send methodName
  end
end

puts  Adder.new(10).helloworld
```

This defines the method in the class, using the variable you sent as the variable name.

Here's a working example: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/e8bf5

Comment: This is quite wired example of how far we can go away from the OP question. Using `method_missing` to define methods in runtime can give you a several "happy" hours of debug in case if something goes wrong. You should do it with caution.